# Win10 doesn't let me enter letter P in user password (login screen)

Tags: windows-10

I'm serious. There's nothing wrong with my keyboard, I've tried different ones. On all of them `p` is dead. I'm currently using the alt code for logging in. It's super strange since even if some program bound on p, I wouldn't expect the shortcut to work in input fields. Any idea?

Comment: Try to boot in Safe mode.

Comment: Pleas edit the Question to indicate if you can successfully type the letter p in the midst of a login (you might be writing this Question from another computer)

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what language packs you have installed and what keyboard layouts you have installed.  Please do not provide this information in a comment.

Comment: I had this problem too. The 'P' key did not work on the login screen so I had to use Alt+112 to enter my password. But the key did work when I logged in. After I locked my screen the key stopped working again. A reboot solved it though.

Comment: Saw this happen today on a business HP pc. Seems to have happened overnight while the desktop was locked. The system was freshly rebooted for patch tuesday half an hour before locking, and after that the only logged activity was some minor updates (spotify, vclibs.140, dotnet runtime 2.2). I also observed the issue while connected over VNC. Signing in made it go away, and I couldn't reproduce it after returning to the login screen. My suspicion is that some running software registered 'p' as a hotkey (maybe spotify uwp?). I didn't know hotkeys work on the lock screen, but it seems like it?

Answer (score 3):

For me the fix was to lock the screen with `Ctrl+Alt+Del` > `Lock`. It seems to have something to do with the `Win+P` combination, as described [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234758-specific-letters-not-working-at-windows-10-login-screen).

> I've noticed that when pressing Win+L keys to lock the computer there was appearing screen-selection menu on the right side for a fraction of a second (like if i was pressing Win+P). Maybe two-monitor setup has to do something with it.

If that doesn't work you can always use: `Alt+112` to get the letter 'p'.

Answer (score -3):

I've seen a situation where a peripheral blocked certain types of keyboard entry into a password field while logged out, in this case it was an IR remote, pretending to be a keyboard. To be fair this was actually on a mac, so it's not likely to be the same issue here, but the general principal of confirming there is nothing odd plugged in may still be valid.